# Why don't the WWDC 2010 video capture samples work in the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, wwdc

I downloaded the latest video capture samples from WWDC 2010 and am trying to run them in my simulator.

Samples in general are supposed to run without any tinkering so I just unzipped a bunch of them and tried to run them in Xcode. None of the ones I tried runs.
For example when I unzip and try to build findMyiCone I get 45 errors.

Here are the first few lines

```
In file included from /Users/aw/Desktop/Sample code/WWDC10-SampleCode/FindMyiCone/Classes/ProcessViewController.h:49,
                 from /Users/aw/Desktop/Sample code/WWDC10-SampleCode/FindMyiCone/Classes/ProcessAppDelegate.m:50:
/Users/aw/Desktop/Sample code/WWDC10-SampleCode/FindMyiCone/Classes/CaptureSessionManager.h:52: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'
/Users/aw/Desktop/Sample code/WWDC10-SampleCode/FindMyiCone/Classes/CaptureSessionManager.h:54: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'AVCaptureSession'
/Users/aw/Desktop/Sample code/WWDC10-SampleCode/FindMyiCone/Classes/CaptureSessionManager.h:55: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'
/Users/aw/Desktop/Sample code/WWDC10-SampleCode/FindMyiCone/Classes/CaptureSessionManager.h:56: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'AVCaptureConnection'
```

Im using Xcode 3.2.3 64 bit and have installed iPhone 4.0 SDK

My other apps work fine.

Anyone have similar issues? Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Camera samples only run in the device ;)
There is no simulator support.