# Using a video file instead of iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, file, video, capture, frame

Yesterday I posed the question of why the Apple WWDC 2010 samples for the iPhone camera dont work in the iphone simulator, [Why don't the WWDC 2010 video capture samples work in the Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383928/iphone-video-access-samples)
That question was answered promptly.

However as a follow up question I would like to know how to use video frames from a video file that I put in my bundle so I can "simulate" the input to an algorithm while still testing on the simulator.

Any ideas? Anyone found code that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571656/iphone-how-do-i-add-videos-to-ipad-simulator/3046699#3046699) to know how you can put a video into your simulator. Then you can use that video to test any algorithm you want